# How to use DropDown to sent data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

in MVC Application, i use DropDown list by javascript and Json,

here is the script:

```
//load List
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/home/getProfiliList", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                $('<option>',
                   {
                       value: data.prof_cena,
                       text: data.prof_ime
                   }).html(data.prof_ime).appendTo("#profilID");
            });
        })
        //load price
        $(function () {
            $("[name='profilID']").on("change", function ()  {
                $("#pr_cena").val($(this).val());
            });
        });
    });
```

now when i send form to database at this moment save as value of price. Also i need value of price because when choise something from list price load automaticly.

How with this script is possible to send profilID as Text, included this script

here is code of DropDown:

```
   <select name="profilID" id="profilID">
      <option value="">- LIST -</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

by default when you post the form back it will send the value of the selected option on the select item.  set this to the value i.e. the text you want to send back, then to get the price, when you build the options you can add a data- attribute to store the price, which you would then get in your load price function like

```
$("#pr_cena").val($(this).find(":selected").data('price'));
```

where your options would look like

```
<option value="Text" data-price="10.00">Text</option>
```

the other alternative would be to create your own submit handler for the form and change the formdata for that value of profilID.